# Named router-outlet in nested child not loading

Tags: angular, angular6, router-outlet

I have named router-outlet within a primary router-outlet that won't load on navigation.

In my app.ts template, I have:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>   <!-- Contains the parent-->
<router-outlet name="aux1"></router-outlet></div>  <!-- Works Fine -->
```

In my parent template, I have:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="aux2"></router-outlet><!-- Does not Work! -->
```

My routing for the primary path is here:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ChildAComponent
      }
    ]
}];
```

And my routing for the auxiliary output is here:

```
 { // It has no problems navigating to this route, but does not update UI
    path: 'show-child-b',
    component: ChildBComponent,
    outlet: 'aux2'
  },
  { // Works fine
    path: 'show-sibling-c',
    component: SiblingCComponent,
    outlet: 'aux1'
  }
```

When I navigate the `aux2` outlet using `this.router.navigate([{outlets: {aux2: 'show-child-b'}}]);`, it fails to update the child `router-outlet`.

Here's a plunker showing the issue:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Qalj52P8VOEUnioU?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

What do I have to do to get this working?

Answer (score -1):

I got it working by giving explicit names to the paths instead of the default path, and navigating with 'parent' as the first parameter.

I.E.:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'childA',
        component: ChildAComponent
      }
    ]
}];
```

And

```
this.router.navigate(['parent',{outlets: {aux2: 'show-child-b'}}]);
```